# Can I lag/lead with data.tables' shift inside a regression formula by category?

Tags: r, data.table, shift

I currently build lags and leads before I run regressions. This feels a bit clumsy (even compared to Stata where lagging happens automatically by category after xtset) and I'd like to lag directly in the regression formula. However, I do not know how to combine the `by =` part of `data.table` with its `shift()` function inside a regression command such as `lm()`.

Example:

Create some data (the NA's just make sure that lagging and lagging by category don't coincidentally create the same result...):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(id = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3)), 
                 y = rnorm(7), 
                 dummy = c(0, 1, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0))
```

Creating lags before running regressions works of course but is tedious and (with many lags) clutters up the data:

```
DT[, mylag := shift(dummy, fill=0), by = id]
```

`shift()` works inside `lm()` but I cannot shift by category so the results differ from those of the previously created lag:

```
lm(y ~ mylag, data=DT)
lm(y ~ shift(dummy), data=DT)
```

Which gets me back to my question: How can I call `shift()` by category inside a regression?

Comment: what's tedious? you can just use `lapply(.SD, shift)` if you have multiple columns.

Comment: say you have a dataset with 30 time periods and want to create 12 lags of 5 variables for example. Of course, this can be abbreviated a little but it still looks bad and the dataset will have 60 new variables only used once. (still a good point! It improves a little)